# f2py giving "redefinition of 'foo'... previous definition was here"

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

this is my first question so be nice to me.

I'm using f2py from numpy 1.6.1. I have a fortran module containing several subroutines which compile (and work) just fine. However, one of them uses the erf(x) function which is a GNU extension. It is not accurate enough for my purposes, so I am trying to use an external erf implementation.

I am trying to use one from Numerical Recipes in fortran 77 - where I have copied all the relevant functions into one file called 'erf.f' in the same folder as my module. I use `include 'erf.f'` at the top of my module file. The actual name of the erf function I changed to 'derf', so it doesn't clash with the gfortran erf extension.

However, when I try to compile via f2py, every function `foo` in the 'erf.f' is given the error

> error: redefinition of ‘foo’
>   error: previous definition of ‘foo’ was here

When I look at the c file which is mentioned to contain the redefinition and the previous definition, it does seem that the function is there twice. I just don't know why?

Does anybody know how to fix this? Cheers.

EDIT: I failed to mention (as I thought it unnecessary extra info) that f2py is being used by the numpy distutils to create the extension. The reason I mention it now is that I find that I can create the extension fine with `f2py -c my_module.f90 -m mod`, but when running `python setup.py install` I get the error I detailed above. So what does f2py do differently when run through distutils?

EDIT #2: If I put all the contents of the external erf function file into the same file as my module, then everything works. I don't really want to do this because looking into the future I'm going to have a monstrosity of a file, but it'll work for now until I get an answer to this question.

Comment: Is there any chance you can reproduce the problem with two or three small files of five lines each? (Give or take..)

Comment: @sarnold I quickly gave it a try but what I wrote compiles fine. Now I'm trying to find the difference between my big program and small one.

Comment: Can you start by deleting content from the large one?

Comment: @sarnold I could do this *sort of*, but it is apparent that the error is coming in when using f2py through numpy.distutils. To recreate that on a small scale will be a little more difficult..

Comment: What happens if you try to just compile the file that contains `derf` and link it with the rest of the project instead of including the source? Could be a problem in `f2py` when processing includes.

Comment: It could be something to do with the name of the module. I think f2py has some funny interaction between fortran modules and the python modules it creates.  Sorry I can't remember any details. Is the distutils Extension module name also "mod"? Also, you can get funny results from .mod files hanging around from previous fortran compilations, so it occasionally helps to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a module `erf.f90` and import it in your main code using `use erf` (or whatever it's name is).

I have had some strange problems with `f2py` importing modules named with a `.f` extension, you might be able to get it to work simply by renaming `erf.f` to `erf.f90` and specifying `-ffixed-form` when you compile with `gfortran`.

**EDIT:**

If you import the module using `use`, you do not need to also use `include`.  `include` is basically including the actual code of `erf.f` in the source of your main code (although as you noticed, it doesn't behave exactly the same as typing `erf.f` directly into the main file), while `use` tells the compiler to look for a pre-compiled module.

I have found that `use` works well for me when working with modules and `f2py`.  (my code is basically fixed form Fortran 90).  Assuming a main file `main.f`, and a module `subs.f90` (make sure there is `module...end module` in `subs.f90`, I would use the following sequence for compilation:

```
gfortran -ffixed-form -c subs.f90
f2py.py -c -m main -I/path/to/subs /path/to/subs/subs.f90 main.f
```

Note that you might need to specify other options to `f2py` depending on your system.  For me, with MinGW on Windows, I need `--compiler=mingw32`, since `f2py` doesn't seem to be able to locate the C compiler otherwise.

Comment: I have tried this, as it seems the best way to do this, however I get the same errors. It's almost as if it is creating a definition of each subroutine upon inclusion, and another upon the `use` statement. I don't know if that makes sense though.

Comment: @StevenMurray, would you be able to post the commands you are using to compile the code in your question?  See also the clarification on `use` and `include` above.

Comment: I am using numpy.distutils which uses f2py. However, I have found a solution. If I have code `main.f90`, and another module `subs.f90` which is referenced by `main.f90` but never used directly in my python script, then I add `main.f90` as an extension in setup.py, but put `subs.f90` as a depends file. In `main.f90` I use both `include` and `use`.

Comment: @StevenMurray, sorry I missed your note in the original question regarding numpy.distutils.  I'm glad you were able to find a working solution.  I would comment thought, that you shouldn't need to use both `include` and `use` in `main.f90`, and I suspect at least some of your errors are coming from that.

Comment: thanks very much for your replies, they have been very helpful thus far. I also don't think I should need to use `include`. My current method is to separately compile the `subs.f90` module like you say. This works fine. Then I install with distutils, but I'm not sure where to put the information relating to finding `subs` module. It could go in the list of files in the shared module,the list of 'depends' items, or the include directories. But I've tried these and most of them seem to install without errors but when I import the module, it throws 'symbol not found __mod_MOD_subs'

Comment: @StevenMurray, when you run distutils, is it as verbose as f2py is by itself?  Can you look back through the output, maybe there is a non-fatal error or warning that might give you some clue?

Comment: It puts out a lot of information. None of it 'seems' to suggest what I am doing wrong. At the moment, I think the correct way is to NOT `include` any files, but rather `use` the modules needed, and then add the files those modules are in to the 'depends' list in the extension builder. Doing this it seems to compile and install no worries. But when I try import in IPython it says that one of the variables in one of those modules can't be found. Very odd.

Comment: By the way, for some reason I can't do the 'at' your username thing. And thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @StevenMurray - You automatically notify the owner of an answer whenever you comment on their answer, so you don't need to @ them.  With regards to the problems you are having, it's also possible that you're unintentionally mixing in a newer version of numpy when you call f2py from the command line.  Have you verified that f2py matches the location where numpy is installed?